# Diálogo de download não aparece

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Estou gerando um `xls` em memória e ele deveria aparecer para *download*, mas no final do método não esta aparecendo o diálogo de *download*.

xhtml

```
<a4j:commandButton styleClass="Button" value="Download"
                    execute="@form" render="@form"
                    action="#{lotesEnvBean.ImprimirLotesEnviados()}" >
                    </a4j:commandButton>
```

Bean

```
public void ImprimirLotesEnviados() {

    try {

        SimpleDateFormat simpledate = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHMMSS");
        java.util.Date dateFile = new java.util.Date();
        //FileOutputStream  outFile = new  FileOutputStream (new File("/home/joao/app/tmp/envLote"+simpledate.format(dateFile)+".xls"));

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Lote Enviados");

        HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFont(font);            

        HSSFCellStyle my_style_0 = workbook.createCellStyle();
        my_style_0.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        my_style_0.setFont(font);
        my_style_0.setBorderLeft( (short) 100);

        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);

        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("ID Familia");
        header.getCell(0).setCellStyle(my_style_0);         

        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Famailia");
        header.getCell(1).setCellStyle(my_style_0);

        header.createCell(2).setCellValue("ID Produto");
        header.getCell(2).setCellStyle(my_style_0);         

        header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Produto");
        header.getCell(3).setCellStyle(my_style_0);

        Integer count=1;
        for (LoteEnvDetalheEntity dto :this.lotesEnvDetalhe ) {

            Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(count);

            dataRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(dto.getSeqfamilia());

            dataRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(dto.getFamilia());

            dataRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(dto.getSeqproduto());

            dataRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(dto.getProduto());

            count++;
        }

        //workbook.write(outFile);
        //outFile.close();
        System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

        ec.responseReset();
        ec.setResponseContentType("application/download");
        ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"lotes_enviados_" + simpledate.format(dateFile) + ".xls");

        System.out.println("attachment; filename=lotes_enviados_" + simpledate.format(dateFile) + ".xls");

        OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();

        output.write(workbook.getBytes());
        output.flush();
        output.close();

        fc.responseComplete();


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Tudo bem que ele não mostre a janela de download, pois o navegador pode estar configurado para baixar o arquivo automaticamente. Por favor, complete sua pergunta descrevendo qual o comportamento que está ocorrendo atualmente. Uma página de erro? Página em branco? Nada? Já monitorou a chamada através da Ferramenta do Desenvolvedor do seu navegador para verificar o código HTTP retornado pela requisição gerada pelo botão?

Comment: A meu ver o problema está nessa linha: `ec.setResponseContentType("application/download");`. Não seria `application/vnd.ms-excel`, já que você está fazendo o usuário baixar um arquivo com a extensão "xls"?

Comment: É possível fazer download com requisição AJAX? Já tive problemas com isso e acabei trocando por um botão normal, que dá submit no formulário.

Comment: @utluiz Esta acontecendo nada, usei a ferramenta de desenvolvedor, ele chega da o post, mas não da em nada.

@RodrigoRigotti vou testar isso, mas ja vi pessoas dizendo que o `("application/download")` é um generico.

@Wakim achei gente falando disso também vou testar aqui.

Comment: @Wakim troquei o botão por um da _facelets_ e funciono, realmente era o componente da richfaces que estava dando o problema.

Comment: @Wakim Sua pergunta é importantíssima. "Matou a pau", como dizem. Não é possível fazer download por Ajax, precisa ser uma requisição normal. Com JSF isso às vezes é nebuloso porque uma chamada Ajax pode às vezes ser "transformada" (redirecionada, na verdade) em uma requisição normal dependendo da implementação.

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão, os browsers não persistem em disco, arquivos enviados por Ajax. Segundo essa [resposta do SO EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682556/why-threre-is-no-way-to-download-file-using-ajax-request), o arquivo até fica em memória, mas não fornece ao usuário a opção de salvar em disco.

Para solucionar o problema, basta remover a funcionalidade de *Ajax*  do botão, ou trocando o `a4j:commandButton` por um `h:commandButton` ou qualquer outro componente que chame a ação usando o *submit* do formulário. Com isso o usuário não mudará de `View` e verá o diálogo de download do arquivo.